# Set Maximum selection in CheckBoxList control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a CheckBoxList which includes all modules available for student to select. The number of choices can vary depending on the student and their degree.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="module_semester_1" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester1" DataTextField="module_name" DataValueField="module_id" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
            <asp:Button CommandName="NextView" ID="btnnext2" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="btnnext2_Click" />
```

Now, I want to set a limit so that students can only select 3 modules from the CheckBoxList, how would I go about this using C# and how can I display an error message to inform students to only select 3? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I currently have the C# below:

```
protected void btnnext2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String user = username.Text;

        string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        int count = module_semester_1.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (module_semester_1.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                string value = module_semester_1.Items[i].Value;

                String query = "INSERT INTO students_vs_modules (student_no, module_id) VALUES (@student_no, @module_id)";

                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_no", user);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_id", value);

                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();       
            }
        }      
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Use a custom validator.

Comment: @IrishChieftain I'm sorry, I'm really new to C# so I'm not sure what that includes me writing, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx would be the MSDN article about the CustomValidator class that I believe IrishChieftain is suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a jquery to warn user. This is lightweight as it does not require round trip to server.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var limit = 3;
        $(function () { 
        $('[id*="module_semester_1"]').on('change', function (evt) {
            if ($('[id*="module_semester_1"]:checked').length > limit) {
                this.checked = false;
                alert('cannot select more than ' + limit);
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="module_semester_1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: I tried your above script but to no avail, I can still proceed to next page if I select 4 and it also updates database with the 4 options. Was I supposed to change any variables from your script? I haven't really used jQuery before.

Comment: You need to modify this script according to Id of your control. Use Google Chrome and debug the Java script using F12 from source.